# How can i add bootstrap image responsive class to master slider plugin wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, masterslider

I have a one page wordpress site using stratus theme and using Master slider plugin for the slides.All i want to do is to make my slider images responsive and for this purpose i want to add bootstrap responsive image class to images.
But the problem is i don't know where to add because i cannot find that specific div
*http://www.tekfocal.com/*

```
<div class="ms-slide-bgcont" style="opacity: 1; height: 864px;"><img src="http://www.tekfocal.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Embeded-Systems-TekFocal.jpg" alt="" title="embeded-systems-tekfocal" style="width: 1856px; height: 1044px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: -160px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

rather that adding one more class why dont u just apply "img-responsive" css to ur slider img, dont u think it will work the same way by adding class

just use below code

```
.ms-slide .ms-slide-bgcont img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```